# JsPsych add a button to back to the previous trials

Tags: javascript, html, jspsych

I want to add a "back to instruction" button in my 'preTrial_questions'trial page so participants can go back to the 'instructions' trials and re-read them again.
I tried to add a on_finish: function but doesn't seem to work, so any other work around?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>title</title>
    <script src="../jspsych-7.3.3/dist/jspsych.js"></script>
    <script src="../jspsych-7.3.3/dist/plugin-fullscreen.js"></script>
    <script src="../jspsych-7.3.3/dist/plugin-html-button-response.js"></script>
    <script src="../jspsych-7.3.3/dist/plugin-instructions.js"></script>
    <script src="../jspsych-7.3.3/dist/plugin-survey-multi-choice.js"></script>
    <script src="../jspsych-7.3.3/dist/plugin-survey-text.js"></script>
    <script src="../jspsych-7.3.3/dist/plugin-html-keyboard-response.js"></script>
    <script src="../jspsych-7.3.3/dist/plugin-image-keyboard-response.js"></script>
    <script src="../jspsych-7.3.3/dist/plugin-preload.js"></script>
    <link href="../jspsych-7.3.3/dist/jspsych.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body></body>

<script>
  
    /* initialize jsPsych */
    var jsPsych = initJsPsych({
      show_progress_bar: true,
      override_safe_mode: true,
  });
    
    /* create timeline */
    var timeline = [];

    /* preload images */
    var preload = {
        type: jsPsychPreload,
        images: ["./img/1.jpg"]
    };
    timeline.push(preload); 

    /* subject ID */
    var subID_input = {
      type: jsPsychSurveyText,
      questions:[
        {prompt: function(){return html = `subject ID?`}, 
        name:'subID',
        required: true}
      ],
      button_label:'submit',
      on_finish: function(data){
        // Store the first estimate response
        subject_id = data.response.subID;
      }
    };
    timeline.push(subID_input)

    /* define welcome and instruction page */

    /* define the instructions */
    var page_1 = function(){
        
        var html = `welcomes`

        return html
    };

    var page_2 = function(){

        var html = `instruction 1`
        
        return html
    };

    var page_3 = function(){

        var html = `instruction 2`
        
        return html
    };

    var page_4 = function(){

        var html = `instruction 3`
        
        return html
    };

    var instructions = {
        type: jsPsychInstructions,
        pages: [
        page_1,
        page_2,
        page_3,
        page_4
        ],
        button_label_next: "continue",
        button_label_previous: "previous page",
        show_clickable_nav: true
    };
    timeline.push(instructions)


    /* pre-trial understanding test */
    var preTrial_questions = {
        type: jsPsychSurveyMultiChoice,
        preamble:`
        <h3>check your understanding</h3>
        <p>To check your understanding of the task, please indicate for each of these statements whether they are correct or incorrect.。` ,
        questions: [
          {
            prompt: "q1", 
            name: 'pr_q1', 
            options: ['correct', 'wrong'], 
            required: true
          }, 
          {
            prompt: "q2", 
            name: 'pr_q2', 
            options: ['correct', 'wrong'], 
            required: true
          },
          {
            prompt: "q3", 
            name: 'pr_q3', 
            options: ['correct', 'wrong'], 
            required: true
          }
        ],
        button_label:['continue'],
      };
      timeline.push(preTrial_questions) 

    /* if(conditional) node */
    // only if the participant understand all the parts of the rules, then trials shall preceed.
    
    // screen tell participants they should re-read the instruction
    var reread_instruction = {
      type: jsPsychHtmlButtonResponse,
      stimulus: `
      <h2>Re-read the rules </h2>
      <p>Sorry, please re-read the rules to ensure you understand them correctly。</p>`,
      choices: ['continue'],
    };

    var checkResponses_preTrial = function(){
      // Retrieve the responses
      var responses = jsPsych.data.get().last(1).values()[0].response;

      console.log("Responses from preTrial questions:", responses);

      // Check if all responses are "correct"
      return Object.values(responses).every(response => response === 'correct');

      console.log("All responses are 'correct':", allYes);
    };
    
    var checkUnderstanding = {
      timeline: [reread_instruction, instructions, preTrial_questions], // Replace with the trial that should be repeated
      conditional_function:function(){
        return !checkResponses_preTrial(); // enter the 'checkUnderstanding' timeline if not all the "correct" in 'preTrial_questions' are selected
      },
      loop_function: function(){
        return !checkResponses_preTrial(); // repeat the 'checkUnderstanding' timeline if not all the "correct" in 'preTrial_questions' are selected
      }
    };
    timeline.push(checkUnderstanding)

    /* run the experiment */
    jsPsych.run(timeline);

</script>

</html>
```

A button in 'jsPsychSurveyMultiChoice' trial page that take participants back to previous 'jsPsychInstructions' trials.

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/). Please do not remove stuff that actually shows the issue "for simplicity" unless the script only runs with an API code for example. What you can remove is irrelevant content and just have the minimum code to show and run an example